# How do I remove files from iTunes which have been deleted on disk?

Tags: itunes

When cleaning up my disk I deleted a couple of files from my music collection which iTunes was managing. Now when I try to sync a device I get an error message that it can't sync these files because they don't exist. The problem is that I can't find these files in iTunes any more to delete them. They don't appear when I search for appropriate terms. So, my question is how do I find them, and is iTunes hiding them from me in some "smart" way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For adding functions to iTunes you should look at Doug;s Applescripts. There is a script to [remove dead tracks](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=removedeadsuper).

Answer (score 20):

I've found the easiest most reliable solution yet! No scripts, no loss of playcounts/ratings etc.

1. Create a new playlist, say temp.
2. Select all your the tracks you want to deal with and drag and drop them to the playlist. The new playlist will only contain valid tracks. All invalid tracks will be marked with the exclamation mark.
3. Switch to the playlist and select all the tracks, then right-click and Uncheck Selection
4. Switch back to Music and sort by the checkmark - now all the invalid tracks are grouped together!
5. Select them all and delete!

You can then go and Check the songs again to make sure they get synced to devices.

Comment: Being forced to endure iTunes in Windows because of certain devices, this feels like the easiest option to me.

Comment: Unfortunately as of iTunes 11 this appears to no longer work.  Invalid tracks are now added to the playlist.

Comment: Still works fine for me. I've just deleted some tracks in an album, then selected all the songs in the album and dragged them to a temp playlist. As soon as I started dragging, the deleted items showed exclamation marks and after dropping to the temp playlist, only the valid tracks appear in the playlist.

Comment: Hrm.  Just tried it again and it seems to be working.  Either a recent update to iTunes 11 fixed this or I missed something before.

Comment: "Brilliantly Simple" ?? I'd say a simple menu item like 'Clean up library' would deserve more to be called 'brilliantly simple'... Still, I agree, this seems the most sane way to do it.

Comment: Just rethinking this - might be simpler to do this: after doing the initial selection, Uncheck them, then move to temp and Check them in the playlist, then switch back and sort and remove the unchecked ones

Comment: This 95% worked for me. A few OGG audio files, which I can't play in iTunes after upgrading to Yosemite, were not added to the temp playlist but also didn't have the (!) symbol. I had to manually scan the list of checked songs and uncheck them. Not so bad in my case, because I only had ~50 OGG files, but this would be annoying if you had a lot. OS X 10.10.5, iTunes 12.4.3.1.

Answer (score 5):

The script from Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes is now part of a commercial application, but a version from 2011 can still be downloaded for free [here](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-22626-super-remove-dead-tracks).

Here is a simpler script that should do more or less the same thing:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in (get file tracks of library playlist 1)
        if location of t is missing value then delete t
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: This one removes every second file that is not present on every run. The reason it probably worked for you with five runs is that 2^5 is already 32 so after 5 runs, only 1/32th of your missing files would still be there

Comment: @0x89 You're right, it was looping through references like `item 1035 of every file track of library playlist 1 of application "iTunes"`. I edited the script to add an explicit get.

Answer (score 4):

A roundabout way is longer, but doesn't need any scripts.

1. Export your library to the desktop as an xml
2. quit iTunes and move these files to the desktop / trash

   - iTunes Music Library.xml
   - iTunes Library.itl
   - iTunes Library Extras.itdb
   - iTunes Library Genius.itdb
3. Start iTunes - it will look "empty" but all your programs and music are still around
4. Drag the iTunes Media folder into your iTunes window - Library on the top left - drop the folder over Music or the other categories and iTunes will re-add them to the database, but only the files that exist still on the drive will be added
5. Import the saved library.xml file - this will add back all the ratings, playlists, and songs that no longer exist will be cleaned out of the playlists

Comment: This is the only thing that worked well for me. Thanks!

Comment: The benefit is these periodic export / backups of my XML file have  saved me when Apple burps and I lose some playlists or want to remember what was in my spring 2016 playlist a couple years after I deleted it. @odedia I appreciate the confirmation it worked for you.