# Can I bulk delete songs no longer on my hard drive from iTunes?

Tags: itunes, windows

Does anyone know how to do an iTunes windows bulk delete of files for songs no longer on my hard drive?

Comment: What do you mean by missing file songs? Do you have items in your iTunes library that are non-existant of your hard drive?

Comment: Did you try this method
http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/35813/646

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ipod Cleaner](http://www.cyberipod.com/cleaner.html) did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This link describes several possible solutions:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160411195541/http://paulmayne.org/blog/2007/11/how-to-remove-broken-or-dead-tracks-from-itunes/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 2):

As already said by [ghoppe](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/750/ghoppe), if you want to delete files that are present in your iTunes application but do not exist in your hard drive (they have a ‘!’ next to them), you can follow his link.

For what is worth, I’ve had success in the past using [Doug’s Script](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=removedeadsuper). It’s very easy to use, just copy to your [username]/Library/iTunes/Scripts (if the folder doesn’t exist, just create it), go back to iTunes and in your iTunes script menu, you’re going to have this:

[image]

Comment: The question said 'iTunes Windows'

Answer (score 0):

Use the Comments field.
Write something in the Comments field. Commit the change. Only files found will be updated. Sort via the Comments field then delete the ones without your Comment.