# Re-connect iTunes library from different drive

Tags: itunes

I just replaced my optical drive with an SSD, which I now boot off of (Lion, fresh install).  I'd like to keep my iTunes folder on the original drive, which is still in the computer as well.  When I used Migration Assistant I had it skip the Music folder.

I haven't been able to get iTunes 10 to "see" the old library in its current location on the other drive.  I've gone into Preferences-->Advanced-->Change and selected all of the different folders in the old Music folder, but iTunes never sees my music.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is to start with a fresh and empty folder in the new ~/Music directory.

Fire up iTunes and tell it to use the media folder on the the external drive and quit iTunes after making whatever settings you want about copying files / organization. I would recommend leaving both selected.

Then move just the artwork folder and the itdb / xml files into place and replace the "empty" files that got created on the local ~/Music/iTunes folder. (basically use Finder to move everything back ***except*** the folder containing the media.)

When you start iTunes it should run a quick check to make sure all the files are working and you can proceed with your app management / music enjoyment.

Comment: This is a little like doing http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/701/how-do-i-remove-files-from-itunes-which-have-been-deleted-on-disk/21512#21512 in reverse.

Comment: So happy it worked (not surprised, but glad). PSA Pro Tip: make sure to back up your external music as well as your boot drive. :-)

Comment: Hey, just what I needed, and worked for me too. Thanks much.